# Glide missing some images in loading

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a RecylerView in which each item contains Iamge, to load image I'm using Glide. The problem I'm facing is that some images in the list not showing up and in my onException call back both Exception and model are null for these images.

[image]

if you will see the fourth item in the list images is not showing.

Here is how i am coding this

```
Glide.with(context).load(productItem.getImg())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        if( e != null) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }).
                into(holder.imageViewModel);
enter code here
```

and in xml i have ImageView declare like this

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewModel"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/cart_vertical_margin"/>
```

Comment: Use `SimpleTarget` to load your bitmap in which you can give your desire height and width for load image from server.

Comment: SimpleTarget ? how can i use SimpleTarget ?

Comment: some time glide throws exception in case it won't able to load or some issue like network etc. I have explain best way to use glide , believe it will help you a lot. please refer this link  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39336438/3636561

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(productItem.getImg()).asBitmap().centerCrop().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(200, 200) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap arg0, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (arg0 != null) {
                    holder.imageViewModel.setImageBitmap(arg0);
                } else {
                    holder.imageViewModel.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Still having a same issue and also by using this method i won't be able to cache image ?