# images are not being displayed in gridview

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-imageview, image-gallery

I have been trying to create an imageGallery app to display images in gridview. I want it to display only image directories. But when I open it, images are not displayed. Nothing seems wrong with code. I dont know why its not working.I am not getting any errors or any runtime exceptions. Can anyone help and tell me what am I doing wrong ? Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks .

**imageGallery.java**:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class imageGallery extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        imagegrid.setAdapter(new MyGridAdapter());
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        getFile(root);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFile(File dir) {

        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFile) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    getFile(file);
                } else {
                    if (file.getName().endsWith(".png")
                            || file.getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                            || file.getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                            || file.getName().endsWith(".gif")
                            || file.getName().endsWith(".bmp")
                            || file.getName().endsWith(".webp")) {
                        String temp = file.getPath().substring(0, file.getPath().lastIndexOf('/'));
                        if (!fileList.contains(temp))
                            fileList.add(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fileList;
    }

    public class MyGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        List<GridViewItem> items;

        public MyGridAdapter() {

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return items.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            }

            TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            text.setText(items.get(position).getPath());

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Bitmap image = items.get(position).getImage();

            if (image != null){
                imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
            }
            else {
                // If no image is provided, display a folder icon.
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.adele1);
            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glide images sometimes are not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335409/glide-images-sometimes-are-not-loading)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting the `adapter` and trying to get the images, so You adapter didn't get intimate the images changes or not.

And the data in adapter you never set `List<GridViewItem> items`.

And also `getCount` should return the size not "0"

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

Edited:

Do like this,

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
getFile(root);
GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
imagegrid.setAdapter(new MyGridAdapter());
```

Adding Glide in your project, add this in your build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Change your adapter getView like this,

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        }

        TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText(fileList.get(position));

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        String imagePath = fileList.get(position);

        Glide.with(imageGallery.this).load(imagePath).placeholder( R.drawable.adele1).into(imageView);

        //if (image != null){
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
        //}
        //else {
            // If no image is provided, display a folder icon.
            //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.adele1);
        //}
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: can I use fileList instead of items ??

Comment: But first get the value of images and then set the adapter in list

Comment: how to get value of images ? I am really new to this .

Comment: You can use Glide to load the image, Is that ok for you to use Glide..?

Comment: Yes , I can use it, Thanks

Comment: I tried to change my code accordingly , but I guess I am still doing something wrong https://paste.ofcode.org/AyRjPXUYUCdhLXVBRjkgQP

Comment: Update you getView with the code which i added in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56111467/3904109... but to help those having a similar problem...

In my case in Glide 4.8.0 the adding the following to ImageView widget into which Glide was loading did the trick, wierd but it works....

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Or Also

```
android:background="@drawable/R.drawable.yourResourceFile
```

Or Also

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```